# Power Automate and Azure DevOps On Prem 2020 - Create a Workitem - TF400813 Not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate, azure-devops-server-2019, power-automate-custom-connector

I am junior admin managing ADO 2020 on Prem . We have a developer who is able to create a work item in a board under a collection/project when logged in using ADO .

The developer is trying to automate work item creation using Power Automate . He is giving the correct information in Power Automate at the required fields. When trying to create a work item, he gets this error

```
Details: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user '157adfsd-912f-4244-xxxx-b45fcasda\\firstname.lastname@domainname.com' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=acdb03fxxxxxxsdfdsdse","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

***Question*** : From ADO 2020 side, is there any kind of permission I need to provide to the developer ? I am not 100 % sure why we get this error as the developer is manually able to create a work item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, Power Automate connects to Azure DevOps Services (that is, the cloud-hosted version of Azure DevOps) via OAuth, and when you are creating Power Automate flow for Azure DevOps, the tool tip when selecting an organization tells you to make sure that the Third Party application access via OAuth is enabled.

I don't think that the OAuth 2.0 authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) is available for the on-premises version, so you might be out of luck there.

There is an answer to similar question in Power Automate-forum suggesting that the integration might be possible via installing an on-prem data gateway, but wouldn't really know if it's feasible.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Power-Automate-with-Azure-Devops-Server-On-Premise/td-p/658618